# How can I suppress an http error 440 in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, http-error

Azure Application Insights is a tremendous tool, but we are getting some bogus errors. Specifically, when a user time out on our web application, the app throws a http 440 error (I guess this is a MS particular code) which is session expired. This is kind of a false positive, I don't care to track these nor to get alerts from them.

Is there a way to suppress this in Application Insights or would I have to do something in the code to do this?

If they cannot be suppressed I guess I could set an alert if I can filter out 440s from there.

[image]

Comment: You can add a telemetry filter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take use of [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c) to filter out the http error 440:

In your web project, add a class like MyErrorFilter:

```
    public class MyErrorFilter: ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

        public MyErrorFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
           this.Next = next;
        }

        public void Process(ITelemetry item)
        {
            var request = item as RequestTelemetry;

            if (request != null &&
            request.ResponseCode.Equals("440", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // To filter out an item, just terminate the chain:
                return;
            }
            // Send everything else:
            this.Next.Process(item);
        }
    }
```

If it's a .net framework web project, in the ApplicationInsights.config file, add this(type is assembly_name.class_name):

```
<TelemetryProcessors>

  <Add Type="WebApplication9.MyErrorFilter, WebApplication9"></Add>
</TelemetryProcessors>
```

If it's a .net core web project, install or update [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/) to 2.7.1, then in the Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method, add the below line of codes:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyErrorFilter>();
```